# 2d gun shooting much faster than it should

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm learning Unity, and am trying to learn certain aspects of it bit by bit. Right now I'm working on gun physics, which will be useful for future projects I'm planning.

I have a gun and am trying to add a "Burst" setting to my gun.
The basics of it are, when shootMethod is called, it'll check whether or not the burst variable is true (That part works). Then, it'll start a for loop that only will end after a certain amount of if statements are true and therefore ran. Inside the if statements 2 methods will be called (One to shoot the bullet, the other to activate the cooldown), Then I will be incremented.

After doing a bit of troubleshooting I have noticed a few things:

1. The startBurstFirerateTimer method is threaded when it has already been started, which means that either the method is not working, the variable is broken somehow, or the if statement is somehow ignoring it.
2. In the inspector, the variable will seemingly randomly be set to false, indicating that the method is in some way changing it.
3. If I ignore the burstFirerate variable ignored and just use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000), the game appears to pause for the entire second.
4. If I set burst to false, the gun works as it normally would without burst.

I have been stuck on this for a while, and for the life of me cannot figure it out. I'm not sure if there's some weird c# (Or just coding thing) where if statements inside for loops are ignored or something, but I don't think so. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me out.

I am also very sorry for my poor naming of variables and methods.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shoot : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject firePoint;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public Camera mainCamera;

    public float bulletSpeed = 15f;
    public float range = 3f;
    public int bulletSpread = 40;
    public int firerate = 5;
    public int burstFirerate = 10;
    public int burstAmount = 3;

    public bool automatic = true;
    public bool burst = false;

    bool canShoot = true;
    public bool canBurstShoot = true;

    Vector3 mousePos;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        mousePos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) && automatic)
        {
            ShootMethod();
        }

        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            ShootMethod();
        }
    }

    public void ShootMethod()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread threadFirerateTimer = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(firerateTimer));
        System.Threading.Thread threadBurstFirerateTimer = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(burstFirerateTimer));

        if (canShoot && !burst)
        {
            shootBullet();

            threadFirerateTimer.Start();
        }
        else if (canShoot && burst)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= burstAmount;)
            {
                if (canBurstShoot)
                {
                    shootBullet();

                    threadBurstFirerateTimer.Start();

                    i++;
                }
                
            }
            
            threadFirerateTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    public void shootBullet()
    {
        mousePos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 lookDirection = mousePos - firePoint.transform.position;
        float lookAngle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDirection.y, lookDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        System.Random rand = new System.Random();

        float spreadAmount = rand.Next(bulletSpread - (bulletSpread + bulletSpread), bulletSpread + 1) / 2;
        firePoint.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, spreadAmount + lookAngle);
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.transform.position, firePoint.transform.rotation);
        bullet.transform.rotation = firePoint.transform.rotation;
        Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.AddForce(firePoint.transform.up * bulletSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        GameObject.Destroy(bullet, range * 10 / bulletSpeed);
    }

    public void firerateTimer()
    {
        canShoot = false;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000/firerate);
        canShoot = true;
    }

    public void burstFirerateTimer()
    {
        canBurstShoot = false;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000/burstFirerate);
        canBurstShoot = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait what? Whenever I add the unity2d tag to my post, it says unity3d. It also only shows me unity3d things when I filter on stackoverflow by unity2d tags...

Comment: There is no product unity2d thats why.   Yes if you tell the main thread to sleep for a second. The whole game will pause for a second

Comment: But I didn't tell the main thread to sleep...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't really trim my code here. I had no idea whether or not the problem was in the variables, the functions, etc, so I cutting off parts of it may have made the problem unfindable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a long one, so here's a TL;DR:

- Unity is not thread safe. Don't use threads in Unity unless you really, REALLY need to. Use Unity Coroutines instead.

Now, for the long answer:

Let me start with the 4 things you noticed:

> 1. The startBurstFirerateTimer method is threaded when it has already been started, which means that either the method is not working, the
>    variable is broken somehow, or the if statement is somehow ignoring
>    it.

- Yeah, Unity is not thread safe, so using threads in Unity won't work unless you dig really deep to make them work properly. Basically, don't use them. Don't worry, Unity does provide an alternative way to accomplish what you would usually need threads and timers. I'll talk about it later down in my answer.

> 2. In the inspector, the variable will seemingly randomly be set to false, indicating that the method is in some way changing it.

- If I understood correctly, same reason as the previous point.

> 3. If I ignore the burstFirerate variable ignored and just use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000), the game appears to pause for the
>    entire second.

- That is because you're running this code in the Update method, which runs every frame, and blocks the game for as long as it is running. So, since you've made the update thread sleep for 1 second, the whole game will sleep for 1 second, essentially freezing. Another reason why you should not mess with threading in Unity.

> 4. If I set burst to false, the gun works as it normally would without burst.

- Yes, because you're doing the firerate timer with a Thread.Start(), which makes it not block the Update thread, and just changes the canShoot variable value from times to times. Still, using threads should be avoided here too, because it can easily cause you problems if you need to change its behaviour.

As I mentioned, Unity is not thread safe, so using threads directly in Unity is very problematic, and unless you want to spend a really long time understanding its details to make it work properly, you should avoid them.

Unity does provide tools to deal with stuff that you would need threads, and using such tools you'll not need to worry about threads at all. The tool I'm talking about is called Coroutine.
I suggest you study it a bit, as it'll help you solve not only this problem, but several others in the future. Here is the link to Unity Coroutines manual:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

In a nutshell, Coroutines allow you to spread execution along multiple frames, wait for some time to pass before continuing execution without freezing the game, and much more.

Without coroutines, the `for` loop you run when trying to execute a burst shoot runs entirely during a single frame. So, even though it starts the `threadBurstFirerateTimer`, it does not allow the game to continue while you're waiting for the burst to complete. Since the `for` loop will block the game, as it is running inside the `Update` method, the game will only continue after the entire burst has been completed, all in one frame, thus making the burst shot instantaneous. This after freezing the game for some time, of course.

To do it correctly, you should:

1. Abandon the usage of threads entirely;
2. Substitute every usage of threads to wait for some time with Coroutines;
3. Be happy;

Here's how I would do it:

1. I would first edit the firerateTimer method to be a coroutine with the proper wait:

   ```
    private IEnumerator firerateTimer()
    {
        canShoot = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1/firerate);
        canShoot = true;
    }
   ```
2. I would detach the canShoot and its timer from the burst timer mechanics. It is not necessary, but improves readability a lot. Then, I would change the firerateTime to be called as a Coroutine. With that, my ShootMethod would start like this:

   ```
    private void ShootMethod()
    {
        if (!canShoot)
            return;

        if (!burst)
        {
            shootBullet();
            StartCoroutine(firerateTimer());
        }
   ```
3. I would then move the burst mechanics entirely to its own method, also a Coroutine:

   ```
    private IEnumerator BurstShoot()
    {
        canShoot = false;

        for (int i = 0; i <= burstAmount; i++)
        {
            shootBullet();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1/burstFirerate);
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1/firerate);

        canShoot = true;
    }
   ```
4. Then, I would finally change the ShootMethod to execute a single shot, or a burst shoot, depending on the burst variable:

   ```
    private void ShootMethod()
    {
        if (!canShoot)
            return;

        if (!burst)
        {
            shootBullet();
            StartCoroutine(firerateTimer());
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(BurstShoot());
        }
    }
   ```

This should work properly, but I highly recommend you study a bit of coroutines and try to reimplement it yourself.

P.S. Bonus points:

- Never use the name `Method` on a Method name. I see why you did that, and it is because it would conflict with your class name, `Shoot`. That is also a bad name. It would be a good idea to follow microsoft tips for naming objects, and change the class name to be a noun, (ex: `ShootController`, or as I usually call it, `GunController`), and method names to be verbs (ex: `Shoot()`);
- Don't do physics updates in the `Update` method. Physics updates should be made in the `FixedUpdate` method. Use the `Update` method to get the input. The way I usually do it is by getting the input in the `Update` method, and saving it to a private field (ex: `private bool shouldShoot = false;`), and then, in the `FixedUpdate` method, I shoot if the field is true. Example:

  ```
    if (shouldShoot)
    {
        Shoot();
    }
  ```
- Use the `SerializeField` attribute to make fields editable in the inspector instead of making them `public`, to avoid confusion between field visibility and it appearing or not in the inspector. Example:

  ```
    [SerializeField]
    private float bulletSpeed = 15f;
  ```
- Consider studying and learning to use Unity scriptable objects, so instead of declaring tons of fields to be used in the inspector for configuration, you can use a single object containing options for this type of behaviour. Cool thing is you can make Unity objects out of them, just like you make prefabs. That helps project organization. Here is a link that explains it a bit: https://unity.com/how-to/architect-game-code-scriptable-objects

Comment: Thanks a ton, it works flawlessly (With a bit of tweaking from my code, as my system was dividing intergers with floats)! I would upvote it, but don't have enough reputation. I'll also look in to coroutines for waiting in unity for any other time i need to do it in the future.

Comment: @ViaticShadow That's great to hear :)